# WSO2IS IDP Proxy unable to obtain access token for mobile app

Tags: mobile, wso2-identity-server

I have been testing WSO2 Identity Server IDP Proxy for android(http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/07/sso-for-native-mobile-applications-with-wso2-identity-server/). I manage to setup the IDP Proxy App and test without problem. However, when I did setup the sample app given (azone and eBuy), I have encounter some error which I couldn't understand why the token is returning NULL whenever I login to those sample apps. Below are the error log:

> 09-10 11:04:55.020: D/dalvikvm(19024): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 83K, 12%
>   free 9589K/10856K, paused 22ms, total 22ms 09-10 11:04:55.020:
>   I/dalvikvm-heap(19024): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.990MB for
>   1544896-byte allocation 09-10 11:04:55.045: D/dalvikvm(19024):
>   GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 11098K/12368K, paused 23ms, total
>   23ms 09-10 11:04:55.195: D/dalvikvm(19024): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 10%
>   free 12516K/13788K, paused 15ms, total 15ms 09-10 11:04:55.310:
>   D/libEGL(19024): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so 09-10
>   11:04:55.315: D/libEGL(19024): loaded
>   /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so 09-10 11:04:55.320:
>   D/libEGL(19024): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so 09-10
>   11:04:55.325: E/(19024): Device driver API match 09-10 11:04:55.325:
>   E/(19024): Device driver API version: 23 09-10 11:04:55.325:
>   E/(19024): User space API version: 23  09-10 11:04:55.325: E/(19024):
>   mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9 21:05:57 KST
>   2013  09-10 11:04:55.395: D/OpenGLRenderer(19024): Enabling debug mode
>   0 09-10 11:05:09.585: D/IdentityProxyActivity(19024): starting IDP
>   Proxy App 09-10 11:05:10.220: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19024):
>   showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection 09-10 11:05:21.770:
>   D/IdentityProxyActivity(19024): starting IdentityProxyActivity
>   onActivityResult 09-10 11:05:21.775: D/AccessTokenHandler(19024):
>   d3b276fc3665350818f18f521f7ae4 09-10 11:05:21.790:
>   D/ServerUtilities(19024): Posting '{grant_type=authorization_code,
>   redirect_uri=http://wso2.com, scope=openid,
>   code=d3b276fc3665350818f18f521f7ae4}' to
>   https://172.18.64.178:9443/oauth2/token 09-10 11:05:21.795:
>   D/ServerUtilities(19024): Posting
>   'grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://wso2.com&scope=openid&code=d3b276fc3665350818f18f521f7ae4' to https://172.18.64.178:9443/oauth2/token 09-10 11:05:22.150:
>   D/AccessTokenHandler(19024): {"error":"Internal Server
>   Error","error_description":"Internal Server Error"} 09-10
>   11:05:22.150: D/AccessTokenHandler(19024): Internal Server Error 09-10
>   11:05:22.150: D/AccessTokenHandler(19024): Internal Server Error 09-10
>   11:05:22.150: D/AndroidRuntime(19024): Shutting down VM 09-10
>   11:05:22.150: W/dalvikvm(19024): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x41c38700) 09-10 11:05:22.155:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19024): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-10 11:05:22.155:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19024): java.lang.NullPointerException 09-10
>   11:05:22.155: E/AndroidRuntime(19024):    at
>   org.wso2.mobile.idp.proxy.IdentityProxy.receiveAccessToken(IdentityProxy.java:60)
>   09-10 11:05:22.155: E/AndroidRuntime(19024):  at
>   org.wso2.mobile.idp.proxy.handlers.AccessTokenHandler$NetworkCallTask.onPostExecute(AccessTokenHandler.java:132)
>   09-10 11:05:22.155: E/AndroidRuntime(19024):  at
>   org.wso2.mobile.idp.proxy.handlers.AccessTokenHandler$NetworkCallTask.onPostExecute(AccessTokenHandler.java:65)
>   09-10 11:05:22.155: E/AndroidRuntime(19024):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631) 09-10 11:05:22.155:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19024):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177) 09-10
>   11:05:22.155: E/AndroidRuntime(19024):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
>   09-10 11:05:22.155: E/AndroidRuntime(19024):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-10
>   11:05:22.155: E/AndroidRuntime(19024):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 09-10 11:05:22.155:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19024):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 09-10
>   11:05:22.155: E/AndroidRuntime(19024):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-10
>   11:05:22.155: E/AndroidRuntime(19024):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 09-10 11:05:22.155:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19024):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>   09-10 11:05:22.155: E/AndroidRuntime(19024):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 09-10
>   11:05:22.155: E/AndroidRuntime(19024):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Also, when testing the sdample app(eBuy), aside the above error show in Logcat, there is no error shows in the Identity Server wso2carbon.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gayan, I have finally solve the mystery of this issue. when I curl the way you mentioned, I notice a different type of error. It was show "error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing parameters: redirect_uri". After doing some checking on the OauthConstants.java between the proxy app and the sample apps (azone & eBuy). I notice that there is some error in code for the sample apps given. One of the variable was declared as REDIRECT_URL instead of CALL_BACK_URL in OauthConstants.java for the sample apps. Once I change to CALL_BACK_URL as required by the SDK. Everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put correct values for client id ,secret in OauthCostants.java

While analyzing your logs I have seen that you have successfully completed first step in the authorization code grant type and second step (token request) was failed due to some reason.

1. Could you see any exception logged in Identity Server back end ?
2. Any connectivity issue to  https://172.18.64.178:9443/oauth2/token ?
3. Try with http://172.18.64.178:9763/oauth2/token ?

Comment: Yup, I pretty sure I put the right ID and secret base on the WSO2IS 5.0.0 Management Console Service Provider's OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration that I setup for the sample eBuy(OAuth Client Key = CLIENT_ID, OAuth Client Secret = CLIENT_SECRET).

Is there any other possiblity on what I missed where I can check ?

Comment: Both token link in item 2 & 3 return same exception in Identity Server back end.

TID: [0] [IS] [2015-09-10 15:37:23,645]  WARN {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  No operation matching request path "/oauth2/token" is found, Relative Path: /, HTTP Method: GET, ContentType: */*, Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details. {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-09-10 15:37:23,646]  WARN {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper} -  javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException

Comment: Those WARN was throw when I access those 2 token link using my laptop browser.

Comment: Can you see any error log in Identity Server back end, when you try via mobile app

Comment: After I tried login eBuy using my mobile phone and crashed, I didnt see any error loged in wso2carbon.log in my Identity Server.

Comment: But in http_access_2015-09-11.log shows as below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5A9yYvjguFgU2pMZHlWdFVkc2M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: try following curl to investigate the issue curl -v -X POST --basic -u <client_id>:<client_sec> -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" -k -d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=<get the code from android logs>&redirect_uri=http://wso2.com" https://172.18.64.178:9443/oauth2/token

Comment: keep eye on android logs Posting 'grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://wso2.com&scope=openid&code=d3b276fc3665350818f18f521f7ae4' to https://172.18.64.178:9443/oauth2/token

Comment: curl -v -X POST --basic -u 8CrQl8ZcDgQzT50a0ZEMpuXVagUa:LtRKHi5RLfEfZ_sXjet3XGRipHoa -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" -k -d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=b810b0315d7cc16d7e911f3e793cd51d&redirect_uri=wso2.com" 172.18.64.178:9763/oauth2/token

Comment: * About to connect() to 172.18.64.178 port 9763 (#0)
*   Trying 172.18.64.178...
* Connected to 172.18.64.178 (172.18.64.178) port 9763 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user '8CrQl8ZcDgQzT50a0ZEMpuXVagUa'
> POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic OENyUWw4WmNEZ1F6VDUwYTBaRU1wdVhWYWdVYTpMdFJLSGk1UkxmRWZaX3NYamV0M1hHUmlwSG9h
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 172.18.64.178:9763
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
> Content-Length: 89

Comment: * upload completely sent off: 89 out of 89 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Mon, 14 Sep 2015 08:05:11 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 88
< Connection: close
< Server: WSO2 Carbon Server
<
* Closing connection 0
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Provided Authorization Grant is invalid."}

Comment: Could this be my WSOIS configuration for the OAuth/OpenID Connect issue ?

Comment: I guess there is no issue with WSOIS configuration

Comment: So does the problem lies on the sample app ? or the SDK or was it other thing that might possible causes it ? the "Provided Authorization Grant is invalid." error message is very general after I google up for the causes.

Comment: I guess you are getting "Provided Authorization Grant is invalid." just because of authorization code has been used more than once. In order to isolate the problem from mobile app. first try following command (just put in the browser address bar)                                          https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?
response_type=code&
client_id=<client id>&
redirect_uri=http://wso2.com      after entering user credentials you should be able to obtain authorization code. After getting authorization code, try above curl command to obtain access token.

Comment: Gayan, I have finally solve the mystery of this issue. when I curl the way you mentioned, I notice a different type of error. It was show "error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing parameters: redirect_uri". After doing some checking on the OauthConstants.java between the proxy app and the sample apps (azone & eBuy). I notice that there is some error in code for the sample apps given. One of the variable was declared as REDIRECT_URL instead of CALL_BACK_URL in OauthConstants.java for the sample apps. Once I change to CALL_BACK_URL as required by the SDK. Everything works.

Comment: Also, I hope someone can correct the code for the sample apps (azone & eBuy) to prevent this issue happening on other who like to test the SDK. Again thanks for helping me in troubleshooting the issue, Gayan. Really appreaciate it.